# Rest-assured test failed with nested lists, java

Tags: java, web-services, rest, unit-testing, rest-assured

I'm facing with an error will developping my tests. I tryed a bunch of stuff but it fails every time.

Here is my JSON :

```
{
"evenement": [
    {
        "dateDebut": "2016-02-20T00:00:00-05:00",
        "dateFin": "2016-02-21T00:00:00-05:00",
        "id": "28",
        "tirages": [
            {
                "dateDebut": "2016-02-20T00:00:00-05:00",
                "dateFin": "2016-02-20T00:00:00-05:00",
                "description": "Un super prix1",
                "id": "27",
                "titre": "A Gagner1"
            },
            {
                "dateDebut": "2016-02-21T00:00:00-05:00",
                "dateFin": "2016-02-21T00:00:00-05:00",
                "description": "Un super prix2",
                "id": "28",
                "titre": "A Gagner2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "dateDebut": "2016-03-20T00:00:00-04:00",
        "dateFin": "2016-03-21T00:00:00-04:00",
        "id": "29",
        "tirages": {
            "dateDebut": "2016-03-20T00:00:00-04:00",
            "dateFin": "2016-03-20T00:00:00-04:00",
            "description": "Un super prix3",
            "id": "29",
            "titre": "A Gagner3"
        }
    }
]}
```

Here is my test :

```
 ArrayList<String> alDescr1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    alDescr1.add("Un super prix1");
    alDescr1.add("Un super prix2");

    ArrayList<Object[]> alDescr2 = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    alDescr2.add(alDescr1.toArray());
    ArrayList<String> alDescr3 = new ArrayList<String>();
    alDescr3.add("Un super prix3");
    alDescr2.add(alDescr3.toArray());

    expect().statusCode(200)
            .body(
                    "evenement.tirages.description", hasItems(alDescr1.toArray(), alDescr2.toArray())
            ).when().get("/rest/amc-events/all");
```

And here is the error :

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
JSON path evenement.tirages.description doesn't match.
Expected: (a collection containing ["Un super prix1", "Un super prix2"] and a collection containing [["Un super prix1", "Un super prix2"], ["Un super prix3"]])
  Actual: [[Un super prix1, Un super prix2], Un super prix3]
```

Actually, I try to check if an element has [Un super prix1, Un super prix2] and another has "Un super prix3". But if there is a way that just checks if the elements are presents, regardless if the first has 2 elements, it's good to.

Thanks
Val

Comment: From my point of view, it appears that the JSON api response should have placed  the third tirages item within an array, instead of just being a raw single jsonobject.   If you cannot change that, then you could adjust your json accessors so that all 3 items you test for are represented as non-array items in your test.   If I sound confused, adjust your question.

Comment: I can change the JSON response, so I will take a look.
For the json accessors, I understand and I want to do that if possible, but I don't know how. Have you an example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's good, I found the solution here : http://tugdualgrall.blogspot.ca/2011/09/jax-rs-jersey-and-single-element-arrays.html

```
import com.grallandco.employee.service.converter.EmployeeConverter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;

import com.sun.jersey.api.json.JSONConfiguration;
import com.sun.jersey.api.json.JSONJAXBContext;

@Provider
public class JAXBContextResolver implements ContextResolver < JAXBContext > {

    private JAXBContext context;
    private Class[] types = {EmployeeConverter.class, Class1.class, Class2.class};

    public JAXBContextResolver() throws Exception {
        this.context = new JSONJAXBContext(JSONConfiguration.mapped().arrays("employee").build(),
                types);

    }

    public JAXBContext getContext(Class objectType) {
        for (Class type : types) {
            if (type == objectType) {
                return context;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: For posterity, could you include the relevant parts of the link which you found useful in your answer? That way, if the link goes down, changes, etc., your answer won't be rendered useless. Many thanks.